# Are these systems of equations linear?

Tags: linear-algebra

Are these sets of equations linear? What is the number of variables and equations in each system? Please correct me if my answer is wrong:

**a)** $Ax = b, x \in R^n$ - **yes**, classic system of linear equations, $var = n, eq = m$ where $A \in R^{m \times n}$

**b)** $x^TAx = 1, x \in R^n$ - **no**, its a quadratic form, $var = n, eq = 1$

**c)** $a^TXb = 0, X \in R^{m \times n}$ - **yes**, $var = m*n, eq = 1$

**d)** $AX + XA^T = C,X \in R^{m \times n}$ - **yes**, not sure

Thanks for any help..

EDIT: are the first 3 solutions correct now?

Comment: Be careful about c); it is different than b) in a very critical way.

Comment: Check the # of eqns you have for (b) too.

Comment: $var = n$ , this is true, right? Since $x \in R^n$, and the number of equations must be somehow proportional to the size of $A$... is it $eq = m*n$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to be careful with (c) and (d). If $X$, $Y \in M_{m \times n}(\mathbb{R})$, and if $\alpha$, $\beta \in \mathbb{R}$, you need to check, for instance, if $$a^T(\alpha X + \beta Y) b = \alpha (a^T X b) + \beta (a^T Y b).$$

As for the the number of variables and equations, the number of variables is the dimension of the vector space containing your unknown quantity $x$ or $X$, and the number of equations is the dimension of the vector space where your equation exists. For example, in (d), what is the dimension of $M_{m \times n}(\mathbb{R})$, and what is the dimension of the vector space containing $C$?

Comment: $a$ is a vector and $b$ too

Comment: So, what sized matrix is the product $a^T X b$, if $a \in \mathbb{R}^m$, $X \in M_{m \times n}(\mathbb{R})$, and $b \in \mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: well, its a scalar ($R^{1 \times 1}$) made of all the products so $eq = 1$ and $var = n$?

Comment: Almost. What is the dimension of the vector space $M_{m \times n}(\mathbb{R}) = \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ of all $m \times n$ real matrices? For *this* is the vector space containing your unknown $X$ in this case.

Comment: I believe its $min(m,n)$, right?

Comment: Nope---how many entries does an $m \times n$ matrix have? Also, what makes you think (c) *isn't* linear?

Comment: I wrote the c) equations and now I see that c is "yes", I corrected it... d) is it $m*m$ where $m$ is the length of the vector?

Comment: Well, you know the number of variables since it's the same as in (c). But what size matrices are $A$ and $C$? In particular, the size of $C$ will give you the number of equations.

Comment: Size of $C$ is $m*m$ so thats should be the number of equations and number of variables is $m*m$ too...

Comment: You're good, then.